# How to stream Opus stream from Discord to RTP

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, discord, rtp, discord.js

I'm using a Node.JS Discord bot to stream a voice call over RTP. Currently, in my `speaking` event handler, I have

```
var cmd = child_process.spawn("ffmpeg", [
          '-protocol_whitelist', 'file,crypto,sdp,rtp,udp,pipe,opus',
          '-re',
          '-acodec', 'opus',
          '-i', '-',
          '-ar', '8000',
          '-acodec', 'pcm_mulaw',
          '-f', 'mulaw',
          '-f', 'rtp',
          `rtp://${rtp_ip}:${rtp_port}`]);
reciever.createOpusStream(user).pipe(cmd.stdin);
```

equivalent to running the ffmpeg command `ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,crypto,sdp,rtp,udp,pipe,opus -re acodec opus -i - -ar 8000 -acodec pcm_mulaw -f mulaw -f rtp rtp://${rtp_ip}:${rtp_port}`

Variations of this command produce errors ranging from `pipe:: Invalid input` or `pipe:: Invalid argument` to `Invalid data on input.` to `[mp3 @ 0x5615decebe60] Format mp3 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[mp3 @ 0x5615decebe60] Failed to read frame size: Could not seek to 16101.` Could anyone help me with sending a ReadableStream (opus) to an RTP mulaw stream? Thanks!

Comment: What's the format i.e. encapsulation (not codec) of the incoming data? Ogg?

Comment: I'm using the discord.js method documented here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceReceiver?scrollTo=createOpusStream

Comment: Ok, not possible (with ffmpeg, at least). Stream isn't in a valid format - see https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/2462

Comment: This is for a raw Opus stream straight from Discord, piped into the stdin of ffmpeg. I could possibly use createPCMstream instead, but that's likely extra overhead

Answer (score 1):

I asked on the ffmpeg IRC and realized that raw Opus bitsreams can't be decoded. I instead passed in a raw PCM stream and added `-f s32le` to the input, which is listed as a format in `ffmpeg -formats`.